# How to make button over animated SVG?

Tags: html, css, button, hover, css-animations

I'm trying to make the buttons work inside an animated SVG logo where text smoothly morphs into buttons when you hover over it. But, it seems like the hover event overlaps with the button event and I can't make them work together in a simple way without JS. I tried to use transparent image map areas for buttons but there was the same problem. I guess there is some way to do this with pseudo-elements, and I keep investigating this way, but I haven't figured it out yet.

So how do make them both work any ideas?

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 570px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#EMPWR {
  fill: #1a1a1a;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
  stroke: #ff000000;
  stroke-width: 15%;
}

#EMPWR:hover {
  d: path("M 8.4304,2.1351 8.4044,2.1351 8.4044,3.7244 8.4285,3.7244 8.4285,5.764 8.4044,5.764 8.4044,7.7353 8.4311,7.7353 8.4311,10 0,10 0,0 8.4304,0 8.4304,2.1351  M 15.6924,0.0304 17.2484,0 21.3097,0 21.3097,10 18.779,10 18.779,9.9619 16.8291,10 14.5384,10 12.5921,9.9619 12.5921,10 10.0614,10 10.0614,0 14.1252,0 15.6924,0.0304  M 31.7363,0  C 31.7419,0 31.7461,0.266 31.7489,0.7981  C 31.7517,1.3302 31.7531,2.0873 31.7531,3.0696  C 31.7531,4.0791 31.7516,4.8681 31.7485,5.4366  C 31.7455,6.005 31.7408,6.2892 31.7346,6.2892  C 31.7318,6.2892 31.729,6.2892 31.7262,6.2892  C 31.7262,7.5261 31.7262,8.7631 31.7262,10  C 28.9066,10 26.087,10 23.2674,10  C 23.2674,6.6667 23.2674,3.3333 23.2674,0  C 26.0904,0 28.9133,0 31.7363,0  M 27.1282,0.0213  C 27.724,0.0213 28.1423,0.0208 28.3834,0.0198  C 28.6244,0.0187 28.7449,0.0174 28.7449,0.0158  C 28.7449,0.0142 28.6403,0.0129 28.4311,0.0118  C 28.2219,0.0107 27.8286,0.0102 27.251,0.0102  C 26.9577,0.0102 26.6644,0.0102 26.3711,0.0102  C 26.3711,0.0139 26.3711,0.0176 26.3711,0.0213  C 26.6235,0.0213 26.8759,0.0213 27.1282,0.0213  M 36.3313,0.0317 37.8778,0 40.8022,0 42.3526,0.0242 43.4104,0 46.3302,0 46.3191,10 41.0957,10 39.3417,9.9685 37.5946,10 32.3508,10 32.3397,0 35.2747,0 36.3313,0.0317  M 57.1935,0  C 57.1983,-0 57.2019,0.0819 57.2044,0.2456  C 57.207,0.4093 57.209,0.7128 57.2105,1.1562  C 57.2121,1.5996 57.2129,2.1396 57.2129,2.7763  C 57.2129,3.3311 57.2123,3.8097 57.2111,4.2121  C 57.2099,4.6146 57.2083,4.9409 57.2062,5.191  C 57.2049,5.3502 57.2031,5.482 57.2008,5.5866  C 57.2026,5.7096 57.204,5.8324 57.2048,5.9553  C 57.2054,6.0372 57.2062,6.2125 57.2073,6.481  C 57.2083,6.7496 57.2091,6.9567 57.2094,7.1023  C 57.2119,8.0682 57.2144,9.0341 57.2169,10  C 56.0531,10 54.8892,10 53.7254,10  C 53.1748,9.9949 52.6242,9.9898 52.0737,9.9847  C 51.8645,9.9827 51.678,9.9815 51.5143,9.9809  C 51.2915,9.9801 51.0391,9.9797 50.7572,9.9797  C 50.6662,9.9797 50.5753,9.9797 50.4843,9.9797  C 50.4843,9.9865 50.4843,9.9932 50.4843,10  C 49.4497,10 48.4152,10 47.3806,10  C 47.3806,6.6667 47.3806,3.3333 47.3806,0  C 50.6516,0 53.9225,0 57.1935,0  M 57.1898,4.0518  C 57.1905,4.0518 57.1918,4.0064 57.1939,3.9154  C 57.1949,3.8745 57.1957,3.7699 57.1964,3.6016  C 57.197,3.4334 57.1973,3.2401 57.1973,3.0218  C 57.1973,2.699 57.1968,2.4511 57.1958,2.2783  C 57.1948,2.1055 57.1929,2.0191 57.19,2.0191  C 57.1878,2.0191 57.1855,2.0191 57.1833,2.0191  C 57.1833,2.6967 57.1833,3.3743 57.1833,4.0518  C 57.1854,4.0518 57.1876,4.0518 57.1898,4.0518    ");
  fill: #131313;
  z-index: 10;
  stroke: #ff000000;
  stroke-width: 15%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

button {
  width: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 57%;
  bottom: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <svg id="headersvg" , viewBox="0 0 57.216917 10">
          <path id="EMPWR"  
            d="M 8.281,2.1351 3.0969,2.1351 3.0969,3.7244 7.9059,3.7244 7.9059,5.764 3.0969,5.764 3.0969,7.7353 8.4311,7.7353 8.4311,10 0,10 0,0 8.281,0 8.281,2.1351  M 15.6924,6.0846 17.2484,0 21.3097,0 21.3097,10 18.779,10 18.779,2.3738 16.8291,10 14.5384,10 12.5921,2.3738 12.5921,10 10.0614,10 10.0614,0 14.1252,0 15.6924,6.0846  M 28.4038,0  C 29.5225,0 30.3604,0.266 30.9175,0.7981  C 31.4745,1.3302 31.7531,2.0873 31.7531,3.0696  C 31.7531,4.0791 31.4495,4.8681 30.8424,5.4366  C 30.2353,6.005 29.3088,6.2892 28.0628,6.2892  C 27.4989,6.2892 26.935,6.2892 26.3711,6.2892  C 26.3711,7.5261 26.3711,8.7631 26.3711,10  C 25.3365,10 24.302,10 23.2674,10  C 23.2674,6.6667 23.2674,3.3333 23.2674,0  C 24.9795,0 26.6917,0 28.4038,0  M 27.1282,4.2633  C 27.724,4.2633 28.1423,4.1598 28.3834,3.9529  C 28.6244,3.746 28.7449,3.4811 28.7449,3.1583  C 28.7449,2.8445 28.6403,2.5784 28.4311,2.3602  C 28.2219,2.1419 27.8286,2.0327 27.251,2.0327  C 26.9577,2.0327 26.6644,2.0327 26.3711,2.0327  C 26.3711,2.7763 26.3711,3.5198 26.3711,4.2633  C 26.6235,4.2633 26.8759,4.2633 27.1282,4.2633  M 36.3313,5.5982 37.8778,0 40.8022,0 42.3526,5.5908 43.4104,0 46.3302,0 44.1258,10 41.0957,10 39.3417,3.704 37.5946,10 34.5645,10 32.3397,0 35.2747,0 36.3313,5.5982  M 52.5307,0  C 53.4857,-0 54.2156,0.0819 54.7203,0.2456  C 55.2251,0.4093 55.6321,0.7128 55.9413,1.1562  C 56.2506,1.5996 56.4052,2.1396 56.4052,2.7763  C 56.4052,3.3311 56.2869,3.8097 56.0503,4.2121  C 55.8137,4.6146 55.4883,4.9409 55.0743,5.191  C 54.8104,5.3502 54.4486,5.482 53.9891,5.5866  C 54.3571,5.7096 54.6253,5.8324 54.7934,5.9553  C 54.9071,6.0372 55.0718,6.2125 55.2877,6.481  C 55.5035,6.7496 55.6478,6.9567 55.7205,7.1023  C 56.2193,8.0682 56.7181,9.0341 57.2169,10  C 56.0531,10 54.8892,10 53.7254,10  C 53.1748,8.9814 52.6242,7.9627 52.0737,6.9441  C 51.8645,6.5484 51.678,6.2915 51.5143,6.1733  C 51.2915,6.0186 51.0391,5.9413 50.7572,5.9413  C 50.6662,5.9413 50.5753,5.9413 50.4843,5.9413  C 50.4843,7.2942 50.4843,8.6471 50.4843,10  C 49.4497,10 48.4152,10 47.3806,10  C 47.3806,6.6667 47.3806,3.3333 47.3806,0  C 49.0973,0 50.814,0 52.5307,0  M 51.7872,4.0518  C 51.9281,4.0518 52.201,4.0064 52.6057,3.9154  C 52.8104,3.8745 52.9775,3.7699 53.1071,3.6016  C 53.2367,3.4334 53.3015,3.2401 53.3015,3.0218  C 53.3015,2.699 53.1992,2.4511 52.9945,2.2783  C 52.7899,2.1055 52.4056,2.0191 51.8417,2.0191  C 51.3893,2.0191 50.9368,2.0191 50.4843,2.0191  C 50.4843,2.6967 50.4843,3.3743 50.4843,4.0518  C 50.9186,4.0518 51.3529,4.0518 51.7872,4.0518  ">
          </path>
        </svg>

    <button class="button-navigation" onclick="showContent()">Projects</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Perfectly if the whole letter area would work as a button.